# ios-deploy fail to install on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to install ios-deploy on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11 by running `sudo npm install -g ios-deploy` and it end up with this error message:

```
sh: line 1:  1106 Abort trap: 6           xcodebuild
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ios-deploy"
npm ERR! node v4.2.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! ios-deploy@1.8.3 preinstall: `./src/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ios-deploy@1.8.3 preinstall script './src/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ios-deploy package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ./src/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ios-deploy
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Why is it fail? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This seems to be an issue since `El Capitan`. Either try:

```
npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true
```

or:

```
npm install -g ios-deploy --allow-root
```

This solution is proposed at the relating **github** from [ios-deploy](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy/issues/188).

Comment: I got exactly the same issue under  OS X Yosemite (v.10.10.5). The second sentence did not change anything but the the first one has solved the issue: `npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true`. @Beat Thanks for your help.

Comment: the first one worked for me, the second did not. I have OS/X 10.11.3

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue, the second command did not work, but the first one did "npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true".  Also, once it ran it showed this warning, it would have been nice if it listed that on the fail.  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!! WARNING: You are on OS X 10.11 El Capitan, you may need to add the
!!!! WARNING:   `--unsafe-perm=true` flag when running `npm install`

Comment: second command worked for me. am writing this comment so that @Beat doesn't remove the second command because it didn't work for anybody else

Comment: @Beat, I have installed ios-deploy as per github instruction, but still I'm unable to use the command ios_deploy, is there anything missing?

Comment: The Homebrew and npm versions will be updated at the same time going forward. To use ios-deploy as a command-line tool it is recommended you now install it directly via Homebrew(and if you have already installed it via npm to uninstall it).

https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy#installation

Answer (score 5):

I tried with different ways.

This line worked for me.

> sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm ios-deploy

Answer (score 3):

npm with allow root or unsafe params didn't worked for me. try [brew](https://brew.sh/). Command would be

```
brew install ios-deploy
```

if you don't have ***brew*** install then its couple of seconds. install here https://brew.sh/

brew was the only thing worked on my mac-mini High Sierra

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new Solution, which is working right now.....

You need Download Xcode from APP Store, in X-code go in Preferences > Location > Command Line Tools, then select one of the listed options. After that you can install:

sudo npm install -g ios-sim
sudo npm install --global --unsafe-perm ios-deploy

Answer (score 0):

See Newer StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/59581099/329984

The Homebrew and npm versions will be updated at the same time going forward.

To use ios-deploy as a command-line tool it is recommended you now install it directly via Homebrew(and if you have already installed it via npm to uninstall it).

https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy#installation

Answer (score -2):

iOS-deploy allow us install and debug iPhone apps from the command line, without using Xcode.
The first line works for me.

### npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true