# npm install -g ios-deploy didn't work , it displays error

Tags: ios, xcode, npm, homebrew, appium-ios

I am trying to install APPIUM on my machine and want to run it in actual device, for that i have to install the command 'npm install -g ios-deploy'
but when i am trying to install it is dispalying the error.

**Error:**

he following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/Script-C0CD3D981F59D20100F954DB.sh

(1 failure)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 65
npm ERR! ios-deploy@1.9.2 preinstall: `./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 65
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ios-deploy@1.9.2 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/synerzip/.npm/_logs/2018-07-21T10_30_21_090Z-debug.log
syn-macmini-03:~ synerzip$ xcodebuild
xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/synerzip does not contain an Xcode project.

**Solution Tried:**

1. sudo npm install -g ios-deploy
2. npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true
3. npm install -g ios-deploy --allow-root

**Details:**

OS: 1.13.6

xcode version: 9.4.1

node version: v10.7.0

**Note**
when i run the command 'xcode-select --print-path' following path display,
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"

Can Any help me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I have tried the following steps sequentially and it works for me.

1. sudo npm uninstall -g ios-deploy
2. brew install ios-deploy

@Paul - Thanks for looking in it.

Comment: The Homebrew and npm versions will be updated at the same time going forward. To use ios-deploy as a command-line tool it is recommended you now install it directly via Homebrew(and if you have already installed it via npm to uninstall it).

https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy#installation

Answer (score 2):

To use ios-deploy as a command-line tool it is recommended you now install it directly via Homebrew(and if you have already installed it via npm to uninstall it).

https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy#installation

The Homebrew and npm versions will be updated at the same time going forward.

Answer (score 1):

I have Fixed it with following STEPS...
(Ignore steps if you have already done it)

Debug on real iOS device iONIC App

1. Install brew( with command on terminal ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)”)
2. Install Xcode
3. Run sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
4. Install iOS-deploy (brew install ios-deploy)
5. Build iOS with ionic cordova build ios --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
6. Go to Xcode and set provisioning profile certificate
7. Attach device and run command on terminal  ionic cordova run ios --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
8. First it will fail as you need to Go to setting—>General -.>Device management->Click on your development certificate->Trust.
9. Done now you can run your ionic app on your real iOS device directly with just  ionic cordova run ios --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"

Cheers!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Xcode and Xcode-beta (only Xcode can deploy to appstore at the moment), so I've been switching between the two. Cleaning the build folder seemed to remove this error for me:

`error Failed to install the app on the device because we couldn't execute the "ios-deploy" command. Please install it by running "npm install -g ios-deploy" and try again.`

Comment: Also if you use nvm, make sure you "nvm use" in the right folder

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the problem by installing the "Xcode 10 beta 4" on my computer. 
Another solution is provided on GitHub - check out the following links.

- https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy/issues/346
- https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy/issues/349#issuecomment-405937763

Answer (score 0):

After the below command

```
$ npm uninstall -g ios-deploy
```

You should restart your command line. And than you can run below line on command line.

```
$ brew upgrade ios-deploy
```